# Find string in list with highest count of keywords

Tags: c#, string, linq, keyword

i'm in a bit of a pickle for this one.

So what i have is a list of keywords, for example:

```
this,
keyword,
apple,
car,
banana
```

I have a list of strings and what I want to find is the string whith the highest count of those keywords, I started with .Any() but this returns the first string with one match of the keywords.

My list of strings:

```
This is a car. (2 keywords)
This is a sentence with the keyword apple, (3 keywords)
This sentence contains the keyword apple and another keyword car, (5 keywords)
The next sentence contains only car (1 keyword)
```

Now what i want to find is the third sentence (with 5, the most, keywords).

This is an algorithm that goes a bit above my head, also I'm thinking in linq, maybe I should approach it in an other way

Can anyone help me with this one?

Thanks

EDIT:

OK I got it to work with the MaxBy() method.

Now I stumble on another problem, let me explain what i do in my project:

Basically i have a list of torrents

```
Torrent.Title
Torrent.Seeds
```

Now I got the result with the MaxBy on the Torrent.Title, but this doesn't take account of the seeds. I would propose to do it like this: Do some sort of sort on max keywords, then sort on seeds. Does anyone think this is possible?

Would this work?

```
var results = torrents.OrderByDescending(torrent => torrent.Title.Replace(".", " ").Replace("-", " ").Split().Count(Settings.FilterKeywords.Split(',').Contains)).ThenByDescending(torrent => torrent.Seeds);

return results.First();
```

Comment: Hi, Stack Overflow is a bit different than internet forum sites. Here, we like to stick to one subject per question. If your question received a helpful answer (which it did), great, mark the answer as accepted, maybe upvote it. If any *new* questions arise after applying the solution, please start a new question.

Answer (score 3):

This will be easier using [`MaxBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs?r=2da75c30d5bda7959e5113b702b4bb204a0e4a2c) method:

```
var keywords = new HashSet<string> { "this", "apple", "car", "keyword" };

var sentence = sentences.MaxBy(x => x.Split().Count(keywords.Contains));
```

Without using third-party library:

```
sentences
.Select(s => new { Sentence = s, Count = s.Split().Count(keywords.Contains) })
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).First().Sentence;
```

You can use `ToLower` before `Split` if you want case insensitive search.

Comment: It seems that maxby isn't supported in linq (Error 11 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'MaxBy' and no extension method 'MaxBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))

I'm using c# btw.

Comment: Oh, I didn't want to make it complicated, but the list of strings is basically a list of objects that contains a string, for example object.Title = "This sentence contains the keyword apple and another keyword car";

Comment: Well the object thing i can handle, but there's a problem with the split you do in sentence, I would want to check if the string (not list of words because of split()) contains keywords.

why would i want this, there can be a sentence with [apple] for example, and i still want to count this as a keyword match

Comment: Then I'd say that your question wasn't specific enough :-) You could strip such characters before you process your list of strings.